# Linq to SQL string concatenation where clause generates buggy sql

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

Answers to similar questions are not working for me.

Consider this string concat query:

```
.Where(c => (
              c.FirstName ?? String.Empty +
              c.LastName ?? String.Empty +
              c.CompanyName ?? String.Empty).Contains(searchText)
```

results in the sql below. this actually fails to find a match on last name due to the first case statement.

I'm jumping through all sorts of hoops to find a solution (computed column < forget it, udf < forget it, sp < forget it), variations on the where theme...

```
CASE 
            WHEN ([Extent3].[FIRST_NM] IS NULL) 
                THEN 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (@p__linq__0 + [Extent3].[LAST_NM] IS NULL) 
                            THEN 
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN (@p__linq__1 + [Extent3].[COMPANY_NM] IS NULL) 
                                        THEN @p__linq__2 
                                ELSE @p__linq__1 + [Extent3].[COMPANY_NM] 
                                END 
                    ELSE @p__linq__0 + [Extent3].[LAST_NM] 
                    END 
        ELSE [Extent3].[FIRST_NM] 
        END LIKE @p__linq__3 ESCAPE N''~'')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. But this is Fugly (so is the sql). String concat needs some serious attention!

```
.Where(c => (
              ((c.FirstName ?? String.Empty).Length > 0 && (c.FirstName ?? String.Empty).Contains(searchText)) ||
               ((c.LastName ?? String.Empty).Length > 0 && (c.LastName ?? String.Empty).Contains(searchText)) ||
                ((c.CompanyName ?? String.Empty).Length > 0 && (c.CompanyName ?? String.Empty).Contains(searchText))
                )  
              )
```

yields

```
AND (((( CAST(LEN(CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[FIRST_NM] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__0 ELSE [Extent3].[FIRST_NM] END) AS int)) > 0) 
        AND (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[FIRST_NM] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__1 ELSE [Extent3].[FIRST_NM] END LIKE @p__linq__2 ESCAPE N''~'')) 
        OR ((( CAST(LEN(CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[LAST_NM] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__3 ELSE [Extent3].[LAST_NM] END) AS int)) > 0) 
        AND (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[LAST_NM] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__4 ELSE [Extent3].[LAST_NM] END LIKE @p__linq__5 ESCAPE N''~'')) 
        OR ((( CAST(LEN(CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[COMPANY_NM] IS NULL) 
        THEN @p__linq__6 ELSE [Extent3].[COMPANY_NM] END) AS int)) > 0) 
        AND (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[COMPANY_NM] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__7 ELSE [Extent3].[COMPANY_NM] END LIKE @p__linq__8 ESCAPE N''~'')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the generated SQL, it looks like you might need to introduce more bracketing:

```
.Where(c => (
          (c.FirstName ?? String.Empty) +
          (c.LastName ?? String.Empty) +
          (c.CompanyName ?? String.Empty)).Contains(searchText)
```

Since it looks like `??` has lower precedence than `+` (at least, in the generated SQL)

(Unfortunately the only C# operator precedence spec I can find online is for [.NET 1.1/2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but looking in later specs, it appears that the null coalescing operator appears just above Conditional)

Comment: new brackets had no effect unfortunately